# Check in PHP if MySQL Column in Table exists

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, migration

I want to migrate the content of a Drupal7 website to another Drupal7 system using the migrate-module.

I have to add and map fields.  The fields of every content type in drupal are stored in a table called `field_revision_field_name`.  The value of the most fields are in the column `field_name_value`. But some fields have another structure, so I want to check if the `field_name_value` column exists.

I am joining tables and adding Fields in a mysql query in a loop. The problem is, that not every table `"field_revision_".$typeFields[$i]` (alias is `$typeFields[$i]."_table"`) has a column `$typeFields[$i]."_value"`:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($typeFields); $i++) {
    $query->join(
        "field_revision_".$typeFields[$i], 
        $typeFields[$i]."_table", 
        "n.nid = ".$typeFields[$i]."_table.entity_id"
    );
    $query->addField($typeFields[$i]."_table", $typeFields[$i]."_value");       
}
```

I want to check this before I do the query, something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($typeFields); $i++) {
  if($typeFields[$i]."_table" has Column $typeFields[$i]."_value"){
    $query->join(
        "field_revision_".$typeFields[$i], 
        $typeFields[$i]."_table", 
        "n.nid = ".$typeFields[$i]."_table.entity_id"
    );
    $query->addField($typeFields[$i]."_table", $typeFields[$i]."_value");
  }       
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it is bad design for database schema to be dynamic in this fashion.  What is the business problem you are trying to solve that has led you to use a dynamic schema?  I fear this question may be an incident of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Dynamic schema would mean constantly rebuilding indexes wouldn't it?

Comment: I have a lot of **$typeFields[$i]."_table**  and i think this way is easier than writing "thousand" lines of code. Only the $typeFields[$i] changes (it´s the name of a field of a drupal content type)

Comment: I want to migrate the content of a Drupal7 Website to another Drupal7 system using the migrate-module. I have to add and map fields. The fields of every content type in drupal are stored in a table called "field_revision_field_name". The value of the most fields are in the column "field_name_value". But some fields have another structure, thats because i want to check if the "field_name_value" column exists.

Comment: Have you tried [migrate_d2d](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d)?

Comment: yeah but there i have to add and map the fields, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It realy was something like this XY Problem.

The D7 function field_info_field() has information about the columns where the data is stored, so i dont have to ask if the columns exists.

But thankyou

Answer (score 2):

1. What @eggyal said in the comments about dynamic schemas being bad.
2. Use the following query on the `information_schema` database:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM `COLUMNS`
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
     AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
     AND COLUMN_NAME = 'field_name'
   ```

Comment: @dba if there's a row in the result set, then the field exists in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DESCRIBE` query which, among all, lists the columns in a table.
Here is a description: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html

Comment: i running into trouble with this. how can i check if one specific column exists in one specific table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
$fields = mysql_list_fields('database_name', 'table_name');
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {$field_array[] = mysql_field_name($fields, $i);}
if (!in_array('price', $field_array)){
  $result = mysql_query('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD price VARCHAR(10)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```html
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'field_name'
```

It's similar with above